# SP.WebProxy.invoke vs SP.RequestExecutor

Tags: sharepoint-online, cross-domain

What is the difference between `SP.WebProxy.invoke` vs `SP.RequestExecutor`.  From what I have seen `SP.WebProxy.invoke` is used to call a completely external service most of the time, but I am struggling to find out when should I use which?

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform remote requests outside the SP environment (unlike `SP.RequestExecutor`) you must first whitelist domains using the app manifest file, then you can use `SP.WebProxy.invoke` to perform a HTTP operations to these sites.

The `SP.WebProxy.invoke` will take your request and forward it to the server, then the server will do the request on your behalf using the instructions you give it, then return the results back to you. This enables you to buypass domain restrictions otherwise enforced by the browser.